# contenteditable in Angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ngmodel

I am using `contenteditable` directive of angular js. and i try to access value of `a` tag using `ng-model`.but it gives undefined.

This is my html where i use contenteditable directive

```
<span ng-switch on="editgroupChatFieldFlag" style="width: 87%;margin-right: 0;float:left;"  ng-hide="displatSessionTitleFlag==false">   
    <h5 style="float:left;margin: 7px 14px 0;margin-right: 0;">Chat Session : </h5>
    <a ng-switch-when="true" contenteditable="true" strip-br="true" ng-model="chatMessageName" style="margin-right: 0;width: 59%;margin-left: 4px;" ng-keydown="changeNameFunc($event)">{{secondPresonName}}</a>
    <a ng-switch-when="false" style="margin-right: 0;width: 59%;margin-left: 4px;">{{secondPresonName}}</a>         
</span>
```

and this contenteditable directive

```
app.directive('contenteditable', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          element.html(ngModel.$viewValue || '');
        };

        // Listen for change events to enable binding
        element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
          scope.$apply(read);
        });
        read(); // initialize
        // Write data to the model
        function read() {
          var html = element.html();
          // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
          // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
          if( attrs.stripBr && html == '<br>' ) {
            html = '';
          }
          ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

can anyone tell me how i get `a` tag value using ng-model.

Comment: I suggest you remove all the inline styles from your help (its adding noise to the question).

Comment: Your example works fine.. not sure what you are doing wrong.   I noticed you use two sep. variables `chatMessageName` and `secondPresonName.`  The directive is correctly setting `chatMessageName`  consider creating a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WHq4A/1/ this is example

Comment: @Nix can you tell me solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with a scope issue (`ng-switch` creates a child scope).  You need to either use `.` or `$parent.`

Example with `$parent` update ng-model to use `$parent.chatMessageName`:

```
<a ng-switch-default contenteditable="true" 
   strip-br="true" 
   ng-model="$parent.chatMessageName" >Enter</a>
```

Example with `dot/object`:
JS

```
--controller
$scope.myType = {
    chatMessageName: ''
};
```

Html:

```
<!-- html -->
<a ng-switch-default 
   contenteditable="true" 
   strip-br="true" 
   ng-model="myType.chatMessageName" >Enter</a>
<a>{{"Text "+ myType.chatMessageName}}</a>
```

Educate yourself:  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

---

*Side Note*:  when you are posting your question: include the fiddle in your question (not the comment) and remove unnecessary code, and format so its more readable.