# Contenteditable directive not working with Angular UI Bootstrap Tabs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to create two tabs using Angular UI (Bootstrap), in which one tab lets the user input HTML, and the other tab serves as a "Preview", rendering the HTML provided.

To handle the preview, I am using the contenteditable directive demonstrated [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController).

However, this directive does not seem to be working using Angular UI tabs. I believe there may be a scope issue at play, but I haven't been able to track it down. I have already found examples of "gotchas" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047093/contenteditable-in-angular-js), but this doesn't seem to be the issue in my case.

A Plunker of non-working code can be found [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/oHzoc7seoVysUYUHInyM?p=preview). In this example, not only is the HTML not getting rendered, but the scope updates seem to be sporadic.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this without that directive at all.  You just need to use the `$sce` service in angular.  See this [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/vBCErirdMYamQxJ6lEJi?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer!

Is there any way to edit the preview'ed HTML with the $sce service? For example, with contenteditable, I can change the actual HTML itself after it's rendered, which would be very useful.

Comment: You could do something clever.  You can just add the default contenteditable=true attribute to the div when you click on it to activate it and then onblur deactivate it.  I can update the plunkr

**EDIT**: But at the same time, that wouldn't make sense.  How would a user modify the HTML of a `ul`?  You wouldn't be able to decide which tags to start deleting in the rendered HTML

Comment: Thanks again for the quick reply. If you could update the Plunkr to show what you meant originally, I would really appreciate it! The contenteditable isn't necessarily to edit complex HTML elements, but rather to make it easy to 1) Paste in large amounts of HTML from another source and 2) change minor details of that HTML (such as a word here or there). Thanks again!

Comment: But wouldn't you copy and paste the large amount of HTML to the HTML tab?  Not the preview tab?  I still don't understand why you would modify the preview tab.  Isn't that the point of the preview?  would it be better to avoid the tabs altogether and show preview/html at the same time? Like [this?](http://plnkr.co/edit/4kR23uDOSdkn7KEpYwKB?p=preview)

Comment: Yes - you're absolutely right. The pasting of HTML would be in the HTML tab, then rendered in the Preview tab. However, in the Preview tab, it would be handy if users could easily change minor details such as a word here or there, without having to hunt it down in the raw HTML. Using tabs is handy, since this is done in a modal.